# Inequality with induction.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, induction

I was wondering if my solution to this problem is correct:

Show that for every integer $n\ge1$ the following is true:

$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$

Base case:

$\frac{2\cdot1-1}{2}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3*1+1}}$
$\frac{1}{2}\le\frac{1}{2}$
$\Rightarrow \text{which is true.}$

Induction assumption:

$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$

Which means we want to prove the following:

$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{2k-1}{2k}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3(n+1)+1}}$
$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{2k-1}{2k}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+4}}$

Which is the same as:

$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k}\cdot(\frac{2(n+1)-1}{2(n+1)})\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+4}}$
$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k}\cdot(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2)})\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+4}}$

And then, we know the following is true:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+4}}\lt\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$

Which lets us say the following:

$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k}\cdot(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2)})\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+4}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$

The beforementioned statement is true because $2n+2\gt2n+1$ and $n\ge1$, which means that:

$0\lt\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\lt1$

We can now that this is true according to the induction assumption. Which proves the original statement.

Comment: Don't you mean $0\lt\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\lt1$?

Comment: You seem to be saying: “we want to prove statement $x$” and then use statement $x$ as part of your argument. This is circular and illegal in induction.

Comment: @FShrike Isn't that the point of induction, to see if the statement is true for the value if you assume that the previous was true?

Comment: What you're supposed to do is say that if the previous case is true, then so is the next. What you did was say: suppose the next case is true, this proves that the next case is true.

Comment: What your answerer did correctly was show that the next case is true based on the previous case, instead of circularly proving itself

Comment: Okey! Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To conclude for the induction step we should use the induction hypothesis that is

$$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{2k-1}{2k}=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k}\cdot\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\right)\stackrel{Ind.Hyp.}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}\cdot\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\right)\stackrel{?}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3(n+1)+1}}$$

and the latter is true indeed

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}\cdot\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\right)\stackrel{?}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3(n+1)+1}}$$

$$\iff \left(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\right)^2\le \frac{3n+1}{3n+4}$$

$$\iff (4n^2+4n+1)(3n+4)\le (4n^2+8n+4)(3n+1)$$

$$\iff 12n^3+28n^2+19n+4\le 12n^2+28n^2+20n+4$$

$$\iff 19\le 20$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this makes sense!

Comment: You are welcome! Bye